# CMYK colour using Drawing Tools

Tags: graphics, color

I'd like to use the Drawing Tools palette to draw objects in CMYK colour.  The only way I seem able to change the colours of these objects is to use the window shown below.

#### Edit

Is there a way to change the colours of objects made with Drawing Tools that will allow me to enter the C, M, Y, K values into input fields?

[image]

Comment: Hello... Please tell me if this can help you: `Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot[Sin[#] & /@ Range@20, PlotStyle -> {Thick, color}], {color, Gray, ColorSlider}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since as far as I can tell the Drawing Tools palette always uses the system (e.g. Windows) color picker I don't think it is (presently) possible to solve your first question.

Your second question has more possibility:

> Is there a way to change the colours of objects made with Drawing Tools that will allow me to enter the C, M, Y, K values into input fields?

I believe that the functionality on which I shall depend was introduced in version 10.

Let's start with first example from the [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Graphics.html) documentation:

```
gr = Graphics[{Thick, Green, Rectangle[{0, -1}, {2, 1}], Red, Disk[], Blue, 
   Circle[{2, 0}], Yellow, Polygon[{{2, 0}, {4, 1}, {4, -1}}], Purple, Arrowheads[Large], 
   Arrow[{{4, 3/2}, {0, 3/2}, {0, 0}}], Black, Dashed, Line[{{-1, 0}, {4, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

Although entered with directives here such a graphic could be constructed using the Drawing Tools.

We can convert this into an editable form by applying [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html) to the head using [`Operate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Operate.html), and we can convert all color directives to [`CMYKColor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CMYKColor.html) type:

```
Operate[Defer, gr /. c_?ColorQ :> ToColor[c, CMYKColor]]
```

[image]

If we click on any of the color squares we get a CMYK setter like this:

[image]

After changing the color and clicking OK we can evaluate the cell to render the new Graphics:

[image]